# Was there a Fifth Horseman?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

In [*Now You See Me*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/) the legend says that The Eye only takes new members twice a century. When would Rhodes have been accepted? Certainly not fifty years ago. One might assume that his role in everything that happened was his attempt to get accepted and that he was indeed the Fifth Horseman that nobody else knew about.

If that is the case, why is he the one welcoming them to The Eye at the end as if he was already a member?

Comment: Just because they only take members twice a century, doesn't mean the inductions are 50 years apart. Remember as well, this was in the beginning of this century, Rhodes could have been inducted anytime during the last.

Comment: Some of these in the series are lame, but some are pretty good.  Watch this one:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2bqfDrtd6M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because The Eye only takes members twice a century, doesn't mean the inductions are *exactly 50 years apart*. Remember as well, this group was in the beginning of this century: Rhodes could have been inducted anytime during the last, though I would assume it was towards the latter half.

(NOTE: At the request of @SonnyBurnett, I'm reposting this from a comment to an answer.)

Comment: I think the language could be interpreted either way, so I'll accept that as a possibility. I don't really see why it would be worth mentioning that they take new members twice a century if it could happen at any time. I still think this is something the screenwriters did not think through, though I could be wrong.